# remove items from set that pass a certain test python

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I need to remove any items that have `None` value for a certain dict key in a python set. Given a simple set:

```
In [7]: z
Out[7]: {None, 1, 2}

In [8]: for item in z:
   ...:     if not item:
   ...:         z.remove(item)
   ...:         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-680a51a37622> in <module>()
----> 1 for item in z:
      2     if not item:
      3         z.remove(item)
      4 

RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration
```

I can't see why, but it won't let me remove objects during iteration. How can I run a dynamic truth check and remove items from sets? Thank you

Comment: `z = {item for item in z if item is not None}`

Comment: @PeterWood, his test was for truthiness, not Noneness. Try: `z = {item for item in z if item}`

Comment: @Robᵩ That would remove `0` from the set.

Comment: well that syntax should support any callback that evaluates bool

Comment: @PeterWood -- exactly, just as his current code intends. Of course, his prose says otherwise. I'm no longer sure which of us reads his question correctly.

Comment: @Robᵩ I jump to assume the code is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rob has a good answer if you want to retain the structure of your code; otherwise, you can use a comprehension to do this in a single line.

```
example_set = {None, 1, 2}
filtered_set = {item for item in example_set if item}

print(filtered_set) # {1, 2}
```

If your logic is more complex than just `if item`, then it's probably better to keep the `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try making a copy of the set first:

```
for item in list(z):
    if not item:
        z.remove(item)
```

Comment: While I agree with the approach, why not `z.copy()` instead of `list(z)`?

Answer (score 0):

This error is very common when the `for` cycle is used to walk on a list or dictionary. The problem is that you intend change the content of the dictionary while you walk through of this.

In this case one solution is use a index for walk through of the dictionary, something like:

```
for i in range( len(dic) ):
```

But you are using `SET`, the `SET` object in python 3 have a method called `discard` that you can use to do what you intended. For example:

```
z = {None, 1, 2}
z.discard(None)
print(z)
```